# Form Dlookup textbox Control Source

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am building a form and having trouble with getting the DLookup to function correctly.

Here is what I have. I have a query which contains employee information relating to Profits and Loss.
so things like name, salary, etc.

Now I am creating a form where I can see a listbox of my employees on the left and when I click on one of the entries in the listbox it populates a series of text boxes with the various values of the fields from that specific record.

I am using access 2007
I built a listbox off a query which contains all the fields that I want to get the data populated from. however I am having trouble configuing the Control source of the text boxes so that they will populate with that employee's data.

Could someone please help? Should I use a VBA onclick event instead or is there a way I can get the effect that I am looking for simply by modifying the Control source for the specific textboxes that I want to populate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"I built a listbox off a query which contains all the fields that I want to get the data populated from"*

Since the listbox columns contain everything you need to populate the text boxes, use the list box's *After Update* event to load the text boxes.

```vb
Me.TextBox1.Value = Me.YourListBox.Column(0)
Me.TextBox2.Value = Me.YourListBox.Column(1)
Me.TextBox3.Value = Me.YourListBox.Column(2)
```

Notice the listbox column numbering starts from zero.